# Can I do anything to brace a concrete wall being broken by a tree?

Tags: concrete, tree

[image]We are looking to replace the deck that was rotten at the back of our garden but the tree between all the surrounding houses is causing the wall to crack. Is there anything we can do to brace the wall and stop this getting worse?

Comment: That wall is a goner.  It is a danger and should be removed.

Comment: If the tree is yours, removing the tree would be first idea.  If can't or do not want to remove the tree, moving the wall away/some place else is second.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get calling some trades folk and see what they can quote me :)